# Ejecutar script dependiendo del ancho de pantalla

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo una pagina sencilla en la cual se modifica la propiedad background-size al hacer scroll, lo que quiero hacer es que en resoluciones de 900px o menos no se ejecute esta función, por lo cual tengo el siguiente código JavaScript:

```
let header = document.querySelector("header");

window.onresize = function() {
    let anchoV1 = window.innerWidth;
    console.log("width: ", anchoV1, "px");   
    if (anchoV1 <= 900){
        header.style.backgroundSize = "cover"; 
                    
    }else{        
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
            header.style.backgroundSize = 160 - + window.pageYOffset/12+"%";
            header.style.opacity = 1 - + window.pageYOffset/700 + "";            
        })
    }
}
```

y el css:

```
 header{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     height: 100vh;
     background: url("img/mountains-1412683_1280.png");
     background-size: 160%;
     background-position: center;
 }
```

probando esto inspeccionando la pagina, pasa que para se ejecute el condicional primero debo redimensionar la pagina, después de eso en los dispositivos de resoluciones mayores a 900px ejecuta su parte de código correspondiente, todo normal, el problema es que al pasar a una resolución menor a 900px también ejecuta el bloque de código que tiene "else" (para ver el problema primero probar en resoluciones mayores a 900px y luego pasar a una menor que 900px).

Comment: En vez de un `else` por que no pones un `else if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás asignando el evento `scroll` dentro de otro evento que solo se va a disparar cada vez que se cambie el tamaño de la ventana y, de paso, creando múltiples "escuchadores" de `scroll`.

Ambos eventos deben ser independientes y en ambos tienes que verificar si se cumple la condición deseada.

```
let header = document.querySelector("header");

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    let anchoV1 = window.innerWidth;
    console.log("width: ", anchoV1, "px");   
    if(anchoV1 <= 900) {
        header.style.backgroundSize = "cover"; 
    } else {
        // Valor cuando el tamaño de pantalla sea mayor
    }
});
// Crear evento por separado para desplazamiento
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    // Analizar ancho de pantalla
    if(window.innerWidth > 900) {
        // Aplicar solo cuando el ancho de pantalla es mayor
        header.style.backgroundSize = 160 - + window.pageYOffset/12+"%";
        header.style.opacity = 1 - + window.pageYOffset/700 + "";
    }
});
```